# How to enable native resolution for all devices with LaunchScreen.storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios-simulator, xcode7

I've got this problem: my app flickers when I use simulator of `iPhone 6` Plus (with `iOS 9.3`) and iPhone `6s Plus` (with `iOS 9.3`).

I think that this problem is caused by the resolution of my LaunchScreen.

So, how can I enable native resolution for all devices with `LaunchScreen.storyboard`?

Comment: If you are using `LaunchScreen.storyboard` as Main Interface, native resolutions for all devices are already enabled.

Comment: @BhumitMehta then, in your opinion, what cause my problem? 
It could be a problem caused by simulators?

Comment: What do you mean by "flickers"? Does it flicker all the time, or only on startup (i.e. when the app "switches" from launch screen to your initial view controller)?

Comment: @Losiowaty you're right, I wasn't clear. The UITableView separator flickering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens on simulator only, the same will not happen on the device, On your simulator resize it using your keyboard buttons:

command1

command2

command3

command4